# Graph theory related problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I've just started learning about graph theory and I am doing some exercises online.

This is the question I'm currently on:

What is the number of edges in a $3$-regular graph that has $6$ vertices?

---

What is the best approach to take for working this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

A graph is 3-regular if all its vertices have degree 3. Now, by the [Handshaking Lemma](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), $$\sum \deg v = 2|E|$$

As, $\sum \deg v = 3\times 6 =18$, What is $|E|$?

Answer (score 0):

This question is best done by double counting.

Each vertex has $3$ edges associated, and there are $6$ vertices, so that makes $18$ edges.

However, each edge is counted twice, once at each vertex the edge connects, so divide $18$ by $2$ and you get $9$, which is your desired answer.